# React Js Error when building projects

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

When I try to build my project it works but when it gets to the call for the database i get the error

```
./node_modules/msnodesqlv8/lib/sqlserver.native.js
module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'

./node_modules/msnodesqlv8/lib/tableMgr.js
module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'
```

Im not sure what the error is telling me i've tried reinstalling the package and clearing cache aswell as npm install what am i missing here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node's built-in modules (such as `path`, `fs` and `http`) are only available in Node, not the browser. The `msnodesqlv8` module makes use of `fs`, and most likely native code, so it too cannot run in the browser. This is one of the downsides of NPM being used for both back-end and front-end development - sometimes (especially for beginners) it's hard to tell which libraries work in which environments.

If you want to connect to a database from your front-end application, you have to expose it via HTTP - either by having a REST service of your own that delegates to the database, or potentially by using a database that has a REST service built-in.

Alternatively, if you don't need to make your data accessible from multiple machines, you can use some kind of browser-based storage to persist your data, such as [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/). If you want to use SQL Server, though, you're going to have to take the REST route.

Comment: So i cant use msnodesqlv8 then

Comment: What should I use instead of that in your opinion for connecting webserver to a local database @JoeClay

Comment: ive tried using MSSQL module but that errors saying cant resolve tls, net, dns, dgram

Comment: @andywilson: I've edited my answer to provide an alternative solution. Effectively, if you want to use a database, you need some kind of server component as well as your front-end React client. A simple [Express](https://expressjs.com/) server would suffice - in the Express application's code, you could then use `msnodesqlv8` (or something similar) to connect to your database.

Comment: Thank you @JoeClay

Comment: @andywilson: No problem - please accept the answer if it helped you understand things :) I've also added a few extra suggestions - if you're only ever going to be running this app locally, SQL Server may be overkill, and you may be able to avoid needing a server.